# SharePoint workflow new document upload

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

Hello this is probably really simple but I do not have much experience with creating workflows

I am using SharePoint WSS 3.0 on SBS 2008

I want an email to be sent automatically when a new document is added to a document library when a user clicks the new button and fills out the document, then saves it to the library

I have figured out how to send the email but I cant get it to send the email automatically upon creation of the new document, I always have to manually start the workflow

I have selected "Automatically start this workflow when a new item is created

I know I need to create a condition but I'm unsure what I need to create?

Here is my workflow

http://cl.ly/image/2K2r3r3F1Z1O

Here are the columns in the document library

http://cl.ly/image/433i450s1D3O

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

Check the workflow settings. It may be set to "No New Instances", which happens when you redeploy workflows.

Comment: Hi Colin, I have checked the Workflow settings and its set to Allow, I have just tried to use the workflow and it appears to be stuck in a starting status http://cl.ly/image/300410093r3b